# Example complex XML file?

Tags: xml, database

I would like to test something and for it I need a complex XML file of decent size(few hundred kilobytes at least). Does anyone know where I can get such a file? Everything I've seen on the internet is short and simple examples.

By "complex" I mean I also want some form of relationships and nesting between elements of the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Try using XMark to generate a real world type file upto several gig](http://www.xml-benchmark.org/generator.html)s, if you want a ready made one - [38 MB - here you go](http://www.ins.cwi.nl/projects/xmark/Assets/standard.gz)

Answer (score 7):

well,

try taking a word document and saving it as Word XML...

should be convoluted enough for any test.

Answer (score 5):

Try the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) itself it is 221kb

Answer (score 2):

You could download OMG's [MOF model for CWM 1.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/CWM/20020501/).  It is about 1.1 MB.

Answer (score 1):

Any web.config file should do the trick ;)

Comment: Apparently ASP.NET 4 tries to address this with much cleaner web.config files. This video shows a 9 line file for a blank webpage: http://www.asp.net/aspnet-4/videos/aspnet-4-quick-hit-clean-webconfig-files

Answer (score -4):

If you just want it to be a big file size, can you try to just repeat some elements in the XML file?

For instance, write a small program to repeat the  element until the file gets big enough for you.

```
<bookstore>
    <book>Book1</book>
     ....
    <book>Book1000</book>
</bookstore>
```